# Is there a plugin or extension that allows to use DWR remote calls as a YUI Data Source?

Tags: javascript, yui, dwr

Is there a plugin or extension that allows to use DWR remote calls as a YUI Data Source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no plugin to do that. DwrYuiDataSource currently supports remote methods of the form

```
public ReturnType methodName(String query)
```

But could easily be extended to take beforeArgs and afterArgs so that it
supports

```
public ReturnType methodName(Object beforeArg1, Object beforeArg2,
    String query, Object afterArg1, Object afterArg2)
```

**javascript: DwrYuiDataSource**

```
mypackage.DwrYuiDataSource = function(remoteMethod) {
    this.remoteMethod = remoteMethod;
    this._init();
};

mypackage.DwrYuiDataSource.prototype = new YAHOO.widget.DataSource();

mypackage.DwrYuiDataSource.prototype.doQuery = function(oCallbackFn,
sQuery, oParent) {
    var oSelf = this;
    this.remoteMethod(sQuery, function(aResults) {
        var resultObj = {};
        resultObj.query = decodeURIComponent(sQuery);
        resultObj.results = aResults;
        oSelf._addCacheElem(resultObj);      
        oSelf.getResultsEvent.fire(oSelf, oParent, sQuery, aResults);
        oCallbackFn(sQuery, aResults, oParent);
    });
};
```